# How to improve FlatList render performance for large list with ReactNative 0.43?

Tags: performance, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render a list of ~250 images in 3 columns using FlatList in RN0.43, and I change the width of the images in the onLayout function of the FlatList to fit the width of screen.

The initial performance is ok, but after some scrolling up/down, sometimes it takes a second or 2 until images are shown.

it is even worse if I change to screen orientation, it takes 2~3 seconds to get screen updated.

a few findings:

1. after screen rotation, it takes a second or 2 until FlatList.onLayout is called
2. after FlatList.onLayout and update of image width, each image (about half of the list, ~150 images; while only ~15 are shown) is rendered 2~4 times, while render() is only called once.

question:

1. how can I modify the code to improve the performance?
2. in the getItemLayout() of a multicolumn list, should the offset be something like (itemHeight + separatorHeight) * (index%numColumns)?

Thanks.

tested on: GalaxySII (4.1.2) and Android SDK emulator (7.1.1)

```
var data = [
    require('./res/img/Search.png'),
    require('./res/img/test - Copy.png'),
    // ~250 items
    ...];

class app extends React.Component {
    renderItem (info, width) {
        console.log('renderItem', info.index);
        if(width !== this.width) {
            this.imageStyle = {width: width-MarginHorizontal , height: width-MarginHorizontal, resizeMode: 'contain'};
        }
        return (
            <Image
                source = {info.item}
                key = {info.index}
                style={this.imageStyle}/>
            );
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Test.render');
        return (
            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
            }}>
                <GridList
                    numColumns={3}
                    columnWrapperStyle={{ alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class GridList extends Component {
    onLayout(event) {
        console.log('GridList.onLayout()');
        let newColumnWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width/ this.numColumns;
        this.layout = Object.assign({},event.nativeEvent.layout);
        if( undefined === this.columnWidth  || Math.abs(newColumnWidth - this.columnWidth) > WidthTolerance ) {
            this.columnWidth = newColumnWidth;
            if(this.isComponentMounted) {
                this.setState({renderCount: this.state.renderCount+1});
            } else {
                this.state.renderCount +=1;
            }
        }
    }
    render() {
        console.log('GridList.render()');
        return (
            <FlatList
                {...(this.modifiedProps)}
                renderItem={(info) => { return this.props.renderItem(info, this.columnWidth); }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </FlatList>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this in `0.45.1`, any progress?

Answer (score 14):

**Disclaimer:** I know that the question is old, but here is my response anyways.

My app has a hand full of lists with 500+ items. So, we got to a point where the app was crashing on popular not-bad phones. Then I've made [this extensive research about performance on FlatLists.](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips)

The `FlatList` component was presented as a alternative for the old `ScrollView`. The problem is that ScrollViews render all your list at once so they perform visually better, but there is a trade off in memory consumption, that leads to app crashes.

So Flat Lists are a necessary evil. They essentially only render items that are visible, which is a huge gain on memory consumption, but a pain for visual performance, specially for heavy/complex items, that happens to be your case with those responsive images.

### How to workaround?

There are a lot of strategies that you can implement to mitigate your problem.

- Use cached and performatic images, such as [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image). Every operation that you can remove or abbreviate for freeing the Javascript thread: do it (every image is a `new Image()`, so, if they are cached, you have your `loaded` hook called sooner)
- Your list item component is a read-only component, which is supposed to be 'dumb'. Implement a `shouldComponentUpdate() { return false }` or a more solid update control method as needed. This is HUGE perf boost.
- Remove console.logs anywhere near your list. They slow the Javascript thread really bad.
- Build your app for production and test it. It becomes almost always twice or three times faster. Dev env is slow because of debugging.
- Give [this article](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips) a good read for more strategies.

### Conclusion

`FlatList` **IS** a slow component. This is a [known, open and well documented issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413). Do what you can to improve it, and let's hope future releases may fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was having the same problem - multiple images & videos in list in react native So I removed Flatlist instead of this I preferred to use ListView to render fast & to fix touchability issue on list item but Dont forget to set PureComponent to the list item

Answer (score 0):

You're re-creating lots of styling objects for each row of the list individually. This puts a lot of traffic on the JS->Native bridge. Try using stylesheet instead of passing the styles inline.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend everybody to read the article in the link attached below to optimize your flatlist.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Answer (score -1):

Try to set unique key for each item using [keyExtractor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor)

For Example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <List>
      <FlatList
        ...
        keyExtractor={item => item.email}
      />
    </List>
  );
}
```